# SMD transistor identification - top marking ARRL 1S

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I have an SMD transistor. As I tested it, I know it's a MOSFET, but the top code is ARRL 1S. All 1S are NPN transistors and I know it's surely a MOSFET. Please help find the correct part number.

[image: photo of unknown device]

Answer (score 2):

It is an [Alpha and Omega AO3422](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3422.pdf) 55V 2.1A n-channel MOSFET.

---

[image: Image of top code from AO3422 MOSFET]

(From [AO3422 markings document](http://www.aosmd.com/res/markings/AO3422.pdf))

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. But how you know that ?

Comment: Because the code is " 1S" and i dont see any 1s on ao3422 !!!!

Comment: @mohammad  The code "**AR**" is the part number code as shown above. The R is the week code. L is the assembly location code. 1S is the assembly lot code. Many of those markings will vary with the batch. This is clearly shown in the document Sam linked. (nb. ARRL does not stand for American Radio Relay League)